# React native - Override command "react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I'm looking to override the command `react-native run-android` and I can't find a solution.

I'm working with different variants and schemes for my apps, and by default, `run-android` launch `installDebug` whereas it doesn't exist in my project. (same issue for iOS)

Thanks,
Best.

Answer (score 1):

If you have few flavors you can set it with `--varint` flag.

Say we have these:

```
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId 'com.xyz.dev'
            ...
        }
        beta {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            ...
        }
    }
```

You can run it using this command

```
--variant=<productFlavour><BuildType>
```

So to run the dev version in debug mode, we use

```
react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appIdSuffix=dev
```

And to build the release version, use the command

```
assemble<ProductFlavour><BuildType>
```

Example for building a beta release

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleBetaRelease
```

I found this medium post with a detailed explanation hope it helps.
https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command to the `script`-part in your `package.json`.
Then you can run the command via `npm run <command>`.

`"scripts": {
      //...
     "run_app": "react-native run-android"
  }`

Entering `npm run run_app` would execute the given command.